# Observable.forkJoin wrong return type when more than 6 arguments

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I have an issue with Observable.forkJoin inferring the wrong return type and then causing errors when I pass more than 6 arguments.

```
Observable.forkJoin(service.getType1, service.getType2, service.getType3 ...)
        .subscribe(x => {
            this.type1Arr = x[0];
            this.type2Arr = x[1];
            this.type3Arr = x[2];
```

Each function call from the service returns an `Observable<Array<type>>`. The compiler is determining that the return should be `Type1[][]` when I have more than 6 calls from the service passed in. It works fine up to 6 though, it will have the correct return and I can assign strongly typed results.

I'm using rxjs 5.4.3 and Typescript 2.4.0 (Typescript Tools for Visual Studio is 2.5.2).

Is there a workaround for this without casting it?

Comment: good to know that! i think it might be some mistake is service site. its really proved soluction. you can look ito there documents if the say so

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The typings for `forkJoin` define max `forkJoin` with 6 parameters as you can see here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/observable/ForkJoinObservable.ts#L27

Note that there are different ways to call `forkJoin` with more than 6 parameters:

```
Observable.forkJoin(observables)
```

or

```
Observable.forkJoin(...observables)
```

You can also force return types (https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/observable/ForkJoinObservable.ts#L35):

```
Observable.forkJoin<Whatever[]>(observables)
```

Comment: They've moved the src link: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/forkJoin.ts

Comment: Is this still up to date? I cannot find a maximum of 6 params in the type definition